# Definition of harmonic functiom

Tags: partial-differential-equations

definition:$u \in C^2(\Omega)$,and $\Delta u =0$ in $\Omega$,then $u$ is a harmonic function.
I want to know why $D^2 u \in C(\Omega)$,and $\Delta u =0$ in $\Omega$ isn't  the definition of harmonic function.

Please give me an example.Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between the two definitions?

Comment: I'm not sure. My teacher said they are different,may I need to ask him.